# Rotate UIViewController Programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, rotation, autorotate

I am trying to rotate a UIViewController by 180 degrees programmatically. Let's say I hit a "Rotate" button. That said button should rotate the screen and it's content by 180 degrees. My iOS Target has only Portrait as the supported interface orientation under deployment info. Would this be an issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rotate the `UIView` (not the controller) by assigning a rotation transformation to its `CALayer`'s `transform` property.

However, remember, that the orientation will remain in portrait, and the status bar will not rotate with the view.

There is no public API for setting the device's UI orientation. If you do not care about public API and appstore compliance, there is `[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];`

Comment: UIDevice does not respond to setOrientation:

Comment: @Kevin At the time of writing this answer, it did.

Comment: KVO can be used to set orientation in the UIDevice instance. It seems to work but is undocumented. Yet it doesn't really touch compliance directly.